# how can i install mysql in anaconda

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

i want to install mysql-connector in anaconda . but it didnt install . and show this massage:
If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
help me please[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwhlR.png)

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to install is not available for Python 3.8

Comment: so . what do i  do ?

Comment: "so . what do i do ?"—use an earlier version of Python or choose another library.

Comment: @Chris I had similar error message. What is the syntax to use an earlier python version in conda package installation?

Comment: @user9393931, I'm not an Anaconda user but I believe you'd want to create a new environment using whatever version of Python you actually want to use. See [How to create conda environment with specific python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56713744/354577) and [How to change Python version of existing conda virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59163078/354577).